# query not sending to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Embarrassing question here as it's obviously something so simple that's going wrong.
(Also for anyone who claims 'duplicate', I've spent 3 hours on here looking up relevant questions and putting numerous answers into practice but to no avail, hence the need for the question.)

I'm in the process of making a user registration form using PHP and MySQL, everything submits fine, however, I don't see the values in my database? So obviously it isn't submitting fine.

**THE QUESTION**

Why isn't it submitting?

I've done a var_dump($_POST); and the result is :

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Foo Bar" ["email"]=> string(18) "foob@bar.com" ["password"]=> string(8) "foobar123" ["submit"]=> string(8) "Register" }
```

I've also done print_r($query); on the query to see what's being passed and the result is:

```
INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('Foo Bar', 'foo@bar.com', '$2y$10$36UQIGc6OwFrNs/TBfc6letRlrrdRGGoj.lh65puJElDJER08ozQe')
```

The table user_info already exists and my connection to the database is fine.
I've tried using backward commas for the column names, I've also tried not using commas for the values but nothing seems to be submitting.

Here's the code:

HTML -

```
<form method="post" name="register-form" action="database.php">
    Name:       <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email:      <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    Password:   <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

PHP -

```
<?php

require 'dbconnect.php';

function registerUser() {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


    $mysqli = mysqli_init();
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";
    $mysqli->query($con, $query); //$con referenced in dbconnect to connect to db

    var_dump($_POST);
    print_r($query);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) === TRUE){
    registerUser();
}

?>
```

dbconnect.php

```
<?php

$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'foo';
$dbpassword = 'bar';
$dbdatabase = 'usersdb';

$con = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

I'm starting to think this might be permission related but it's on my localhost using XAMPP so surely it can't be? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to not become target of sql injections.

Comment: Can you run the same query from Workbench (with the same login credentials)?

Comment: @KeVin I knew this would pop up, i forgot to mention in the question that i originally did have mysql_real_escape_string but i took it out so i could make it as basic as possible

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function registerUser there is no `$con` defined.
create a connection and your data will get inserted.

```
function registerUser($con) {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


    $mysqli = mysqli_init();
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";
    $mysqli->query($con, $query); //$con referenced in dbconnect to connect to db

    var_dump($_POST);
    print_r($query);
}
```

Comment: Read the comment in the code, $con is in dbconnect.php

Comment: you must know variable scope before downvoting. in order to use $con from dbconnect.php you must use global variable

Comment: reversed the vote as you're now adding constructively

Comment: So are you saying if I add the dbconnect.php inside the function, it should be OK? because I've tried this and nothing appears in the DB still (trying again now as well).

Comment: or the other way around is pass $con as parameter to function

Comment: well just now i've added $con as global, so 'global $con;' above $mysqli = mysqli_init();

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";
$mysqli->query($con, $query); //$con referenced in dbconnect to connect to db
```

You need to establish a connection using `mysqli_real_connect` after `mysqli_init` or use the constructor `new mysqli()` instead of those two. Also `$mysqli->query` uses the `$mysqli` object and takes only one parameter, your query. If you have specified the connection somewhere else, you need to use `mysqli_query`. See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

in your dbconnect.php  reaplace this  line

$con = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

with

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

and reaplace the content of database.php with this  :

require 'dbconnect.php';

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

if(isset($_POST['submit']) === TRUE){
  // $mysqli = mysqli_init();
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";
    $mysqli->query($query); //$con referenced in dbconnect to connect to db

```
var_dump($_POST);
print_r($query);
```

}

this should work

Comment: Warning: mysqli::query(): invalid object or resource mysqli on line 30
- line 30 is $mysqli->query($query); //$con referenced in dbconnect to connect to db

Comment: require 'dbconnect.php';

$username = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) === TRUE){ 

 $query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";
 $mysqli->query($query); 

var_dump($_POST);
print_r($query);

}

Comment: no errors but nothing inserted into DB, var dump and print r don't output anything

Comment: you did it , i'm waiting you ?

Comment: but this is wokring for me , did you reaplace the line i told you in dbconnect.php  ?